# Como fazer o input ser obrigatório em apenas alguns casos

Tags: javascript, html, formulário, front-end

Eu estou montando um formulário no qual o cliente precisa fornecer os dados dos pai e da mãe somenete quando ele for menor de idade. Eu consigo fazer isso facilmente no backend, mas gostaria de saber se tem como fazer isso com JavaScript puro para evitar o post.

Apenas reforçando que não usamos o Jquery então realmente agradeceria as respostas que não incluissem ele.

Obrigado

Comment: Sim, você pode usar javascript para exibir os campos somente se a idade for menor que 18

Comment: Se puder postar o formulário facilitaria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você está pedidindo parece ser algo simples, realmente só muda se for XHTML ou HTML. Se puder enviar o formulario eu poderia te ajudar com mais detalhes...

De toda forma o seguinte código serviria para ambos os casos:

```
if(idade < 18){
   document.getElementById("id_elemento").removeAttribute("required");
}
else{
   document.getElementById("id_elemento").setAttribute("required","required");
}
```

Dá para fazer um código melhor que isso, provavelmente você terá que verificar toda vez que a data muda ou algo assim... Realmente depende do seu código, mas esse get e set do atributo é o que você está procurando.
Fonte (e vale a pena ler!!):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

http://www.mundojs.com.br/artigos/a00002.html

Comment: É em XHTML/JSF acho que era esse mesmo o problema pois o exemplo que eu tinha não fazia o setAttribute desta forma... Devia estar funcionando no outro por ser HTML, sei lá..
Vou testar aqui. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja algo assim que está procurando:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="idade" value="true" onclick="validar();"> Maior de 18 anos<br>

<div id="parents">
  Nome Pai: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Nome Mãe: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <button>Enviar</button>
</div>
```

**JS Puro**

```
function validar() {
    var x = document.getElementById("parents");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/rodrigorf/wt52n37g/1/

EDITADO =====

Fiz uma modificação para manter os campos visíveis porém bloqueados:

```
function validar() {
    txtMae = document.getElementById("txtMae");
    txtPai = document.getElementById("txtPai");

    if (txtMae.disabled === true) {
        txtMae.disabled = false;
    } else {
        txtMae.disabled = true;
    }

    if (txtPai.disabled === true) {
        txtPai.disabled = false;
    } else {
        txtPai.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Rodrigo,
É mais ou menos esse o caminho que estou procurando, obrogiado. O único detalhes é que os dados precisam continuar visiveis mesmo se não forem obrigatórios.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um evento, quando inserido a idade, se ela for menor que 18 os campos do Pai e Mãe mudam para `required`

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="idade" id="idade" required>
<label for="idade">Idade</label>

<input type="text" name="mae" id="mae">
<label for="mae">Mãe</label>

<input type="text" name="pai" id="pai">
<label for="pai">Pai</label>
```

**JS:**

```
var campoIdade = document.getElementById('idade');

campoIdade.onchange = function() { 

    var idade = campoIdade.value;

    if(idade < 18) {
        document.getElementById('mae').required = true;
        document.getElementById('pai').required = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('mae').required = false;
        document.getElementById('pai').required = false;
    }
}
```

Então toda vez que a idade for inserida, é feita a verificação, e muda a propriedade dos pais para obrigatório se for menor que 18 anos.

Funcionando aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/Lejq5x3v/3/
Espero que ajude

Comment: Valeu cara, eu vou testar aqui. era esse true e false que devia estar causando o erro... O exemplo que eu tinha mostrava apenas a palavre required